# IPC communication between .net and nodejs

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, ipc, named-pipes

I'm having problems implementing a two way communication between a .NET and a Node.js application.

I want them to be able to pass multiple messages back and forth between them before closing the channel, but something isn't quite working when sending messages from the Node server.

I can send messages from the client to the server, but when sending from the server the `reader.ReadLine()` gets the data but never continues until I close the connection.

I feel that a flush or something like that is missing, but I can't find anywhere how it should be implemented. I don't want to close and reconnect if possible.

Node server:

```
const net = require("net");

const server = net.createServer((stream) => {
  console.log("Server: on connection");

  stream.on("data", (buffer) => {
    console.log("Got data:", buffer.toString());
    stream.write("Reverse me");
  });

  stream.on("end", () => {
    console.log("Stream ended");
    server.close();
  });
});

server.listen("\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe", () => {
  console.log("Listening...");
});
```

C# client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new NamedPipeClientStream("myPipe");

    client.Connect();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client);

    while (true)
    {
        if (!client.IsConnected)
        {
            break;
        }

        var line = reader.ReadLine();

        writer.WriteLine(line.Reverse());
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: and how you are sending LINE from server? edit: ***A line** is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n").*

Comment: Ouch!! So I just need to add newline to the end of every message!? I didn't know that! It seems to work now. But does that mean that I have to differentiate between a newline when it is part of the message and the actual end of the message?

Comment: Or don't use readline.. Anyway it's normal to use some protocol FX int length , byte[] message.. So you would wait for 4 bytes and read em as int then wait for length bytes... And this would be whole message... Then again wait for 4 bytes

Comment: Makes sense! Greatly appreciate the help! This has taken more time than I dare to think about! =P Thanks a lot!